# Хочу объединить 2 и больше ячеек в csv с помощью пайтона, пример на скрине

Tags: python, excel, csv

[image]

Есть вот такая фотка,в которой ячейки B2&B3 объединение, E2&E3 и C2&D2  ( скрин из гугл таблиц), как такое сделать в csv( или можно в экселе ) формате в питоне?

Comment: Нет, Денис, не выйдет - csv ничего не знает о форматировании, только о данных. Это обычный текст, в котором нет понятия ячеек и, соответственно, не может быть объединённых ячеек

Comment: Хорошо, а как на счёт excel?

Comment: О, это другая задача, это можно сделать - запустить макрорекордер, отрыть CSV-файл, объединить нужные ячейки и применить какое-то другое форматирование, сохранить как файл Excel (!), остановить запись макроса. Часть команд в коде будут лишними, но основные действия будут записаны явно - можно использовать макрос как есть, как код VBA, можно перевести на какой-то другой язык (тот же Python)